Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project
I am migrating existing springboot project 2.7.5 with java 8 to springboot 3.x.x with java 17.
While running mvn clean package I am getting below error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project:Compilation Failure ->
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:206):
Caused by : org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1219)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:188)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:157)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.Launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

In the code i have fixed all the compilation errors.
Any suggestions?

The stacktrace is not complete for us to figure out the cause and share a resolution.

updated stacktrace now .

Doesn't seem complete still, what version of maven are you using? Have you looked into the debug logs using -X?

Yes, these logs are using -X

Issue is fixed . It was due to jdk 8 compiler ,which was trying to compile java 17 classes
